# Bootstrap switch not working for nested directives inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please read the code below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <list-item></list-item>
</div>
```

Html(list_item.html) of the above directive(listItem) is as below(have shown only a small part of html):

```
<div class="active-icon-list">
    <switch-check status="{{ item.status }}"></switch-check>
</div>
```

js of the above directive is as below:

```
directives.directive('cusListItem', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',  
        templateUrl: "list_item.html",
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            // -----
        }
    };
});
```

Html(switch_check.html) of the above directive(switchCheck) is as below:

```
<div class="make-switch switch-small switch-mini active-list-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked ng-if="status == 'active'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-if="status == 'inactive'">
</div>
```

js of the above directive is as below:

```
directives.directive('switchCheck', function($timeout) {
    var switches = [];
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { status: '@'},
        templateUrl: "switch_check.html",
        link: function postLink($scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
            iElm['bootstrapSwitch']();
        }
    }
});
```

I have made directives for the purpose of reusability.
Since I am using bootstrapSwitch.js instead of normal checkbox, I have created a directive.
If a remove ng-if and write a traditional input tag, this works properly.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

But if I use ng-if, `iElm['bootstrapSwitch']();` fails and checkbox does not appear at all.
Is there a way(an efficient one) to figure out a solution for this one?
Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Comment: can you post the code of first directive as well or at least try to create a plunker?

Comment: I have already added the html of first directive.

Comment: I saw you posted html but I asked for directive code like code of 'switchCheck'...

Comment: Sure. I will edit the question.

Comment: @wickY26 - please check now.